# Xamarin - Xam.Plugin.PushNotification - Failed to show notification: Missing icon

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-notifications

Im using Xam.Plugin.PushNotification for push notifications based FireBase.
When i am send a message notification via FireBase website, everything good.
But when i am send the message with "Advanced options" I see in Debug output this lines:

> 03-16 13:44:50.644 W/GcmNotification( 7928): Failed to show notification: Missing icon"

Here is Firebase "add message" screenshot:

[image: FireBase add message section]

Here is my code in function OnCreate():

```
CrossPushNotification.Initialize<CrossPushNotificationListener>("SENDER_ID");
CrossPushNotification.Current.Register();
CrossPushNotification.NotificationContentTitleKey = "google.c.a.c_l";
CrossPushNotification.NotificationContentTextKey = "gcm.notification.body";
```

Comment: It says "missing icon". This appears to mean you're missing an icon. Did you give it an icon?

Comment: Yes, im try to set an icon from recourse.drawable and try to dont set(and there a default icon).

Comment: In message with tite and content its worked. BUT in message with "Advanced options" Its not.